# Texarea field partially displays text copied/pasted from webpages

Tags: php, html, mysql, copy, textarea

I have a textarea field in a php form linked to a mysql longtext field that mostly I use to paste in some text that is escaped by the mysqli_real_escape_string.

Working on it I am experiencing an issue since if:

- Copy and paste text from word editor all the characters are included in the textarea;
- Copy and paste text from a website the text view is limited.

In both cases however the pasted text is entirely stored in the db field. Seems to be a limitation of the text area only.

Any similar experience ?

Comment: On output are you calling `strip_tags()`?

Comment: No I am not. If the text is pasted from a word editor the text is fully displayed.

Comment: Im confused now when you say `text view is limited` what do you mean? Missing line breaks? Missing HTML? Truncated? Also be wary of XSS even in a private system.

Comment: I mean that the text is showed only partially. I am not experienced in XSS, it is a local application linked to a remote website.

Comment: Ok, try `htmlentities()` on the output, I'm thinking you may have a `"` in the text causing it to break out and XSS into the textarea. Other than that id need to see the code.

Comment: I have these special characters stored into the db, could it depend from it? https://pastebin.com/jK9QiSLr

Comment: Encoding could be an issue but have a look at the source, and see if it is breaking the HTML of the textarea.

Comment: Lawrence the text is displayed through a js that recalling the id of selected brand displays all the related information in each field. Please have a look to this new pastebin: https://pastebin.com/Rdj82ySp

Comment: Lawrence with this configuration it's difficult to me to include htmlentities{} to my code. If you saw my last pastebin, do you have any idea where to apply?